# Странная работа sum()

Tags: python, функции

Вот мой код:

```
spilled, sheets = map(int, input().split())
list_of_spilled = map(int, input().split())

print(sum(list_of_spilled))

a = sum(list_of_spilled)

print(a)
```

Пример на котором я проверяю работу:

```
2 10
3 2
```

И почему-то в первом случае:

> ```
> print(sum(list_of_spilled))
> ```

код выводит 5, как и положено

А во втором:

> ```
> a = sum(list_of_spilled)
>
> print(a)
> ```

код выводит 0.

Пожалуйста, объясните, что я делаю не так.

Comment: Вы создали генератор и первым суммированием его исчерпали. Теперь он пустой и сумма его нулевая.

Comment: `map(int, input().split())` -> `list(map(int, input().split()))`. Скопировав данные из генератора в список, вы получили коллекцию, которую можно итерировать много раз.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В вашем коде вы используете функцию `map()` для создания итерируемого объекта `list_of_spilled`. Когда вы вызываете `sum(list_of_spilled)` в первый раз, он успешно вычисляет сумму (3 + 2 = 5), но после этого `list_of_spilled` становится пустым.

Когда вы снова пытаетесь использовать `sum(list_of_spilled)` для присвоения значения переменной `a`, список уже пуст, и поэтому сумма равна `0`.

Чтобы избежать этой проблемы, вы можете преобразовать результат `map()` в список, чтобы он оставался неизменным после первого использования:

```
spilled, sheets = map(int, input().split())
list_of_spilled = list(map(int, input().split()))

print(sum(list_of_spilled))

a = sum(list_of_spilled)

print(a)
```